# Standard libraries still require additional runtime libs? (vcruntime140_1.dll)

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I've created a Windows x64 program using standard headers and DirectX (see below). I was kinda expecting no additional runtime libs would be required for the users. But i got the feedback from some that the `vcruntime140_1.dll` was missing. It's an easy fix, but how do I ensure that users don't need to download additional runtime libs besides DirectX?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
```

Comment: Seems simple enough. Load up a fresh install of Windows on a VM. Copy over your exe. Run it, fulfill the dependencies, re-run till it works as expected. Keep a note of what dependencies you add and ship them with your exe.

Comment: Also I hope that you used Microsoft's installer fulfill the msvcp dependency; and not copy from your System32 or something. :)

Comment: *"how do I ensure that users don't need to download additional runtime libs"* - Easy, by not relying on them. If you are writing C++ code, you are relying on the C++ implementation's support libraries. Same is true for C. Writing code that doesn't depend on any runtime library is possible, but highly non-trivial.

Comment: If visual studio is your development platform, the corresponding vcredist installer exists for a reason; this would be a big one. If your program is built with, say VS2015u3, the corresponding vsredist installer module should be included with your installer, and run as warranted.Further, they're downloadable from MS for developers to include as part of their shipping programs.

Comment: Consider linking the [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019) statically, instead (`/MT`, `/MTd`).

Comment: [`vcruntime` libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) are required to run applications that are developed by using the corresponding version of Visual C++. If you use C++ instead of Visual C++, it will not be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running programs under Windows10 developed in Visual C++ require the associated runtime redistributables: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads.

Microsoft has decided to include the universal C Runtime (CRT) libraries with the standard Windows 10 installation and these are kept up to date via the general Windows update mechanism. The Visual C++ redistributables rely on these UCRT but require a separate installation. Installing the Visual C++ runtime libraries will also verify the latest UCRT are installed in case the user hasn't updated Windows regularly. More details are found on [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads.).

Another option would be include the libraries in the executable using static linking. The program will become larger and care should be taken they are included multiple times. Also any fixes by Microsoft to the dll's will require a rebuild of the program.

Comment: If you write a C program, you won't need to deploy the C++ runtime libraries. And if you deploy the C++ runtime libraries, you will *also* have to produce a new deployment to benefit from updates. You cannot just have the system use an updated version of the support libraries, and take advantage of them without ever having verified, that your program runs under that updated environment. No matter how many times this proposed benefit of dynamic linking is repeated, it doesn't change the fact: You're going to have to publish an updated version of your program either way.